# Can we guess what value the image has originally shown?

Tags: image-processing

If we had a matrix from our image with some missing/corrupted values, can we calculate what value it has originally shown?

[For example if I had this Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asv7S.jpg)

Comment: That depends on what assumptions you can make about the image.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the noise is salt and pepper and is randomly distributed throughout the image, a median filter would be a simple way of eliminating the noise.

You could also compare each pixel to the median of its neighborhood and if it falls outside a (median +/- median*threshold) value then flag the pixel as noise. Replace the pixel with the median. This way you eliminate the noise and don't change the rest of the image.

In your example image, the noise is not randomly distributed, so you would need to take a data oriented approach. If you know the noise is always going to present itself in splotched regions, then a median filter is not going to work very well unless you increase the size of the kernel which would also decrease the image quality.

Unless you know something about the structure of the image, like it is supposed to be one color or have a certain pattern, then it will be impossible to infer the exact corrupted value.